# How parse string data "momo,{auto: true}"

Tags: javascript, node.js

How parse string  data -

```
var strdate = "momo,{auto: true}"
```

I not know how it is do. Me need read **momo** and read **auto** = false or true

..........................................................................................................................................................

---

I writed example work:

**Example work:**

```
if(strdate){

    if(strdate....... == 'momo'){
         //read key auto

         if(strdate.......auto==true){

           }else{

           }

       }

    if(strdate....... == 'poni'){
         //read key auto
         if(strdate.......auto==true){

           }else{

           }

       }
}
```

---

**I'm trying to**

```
var jsonpack = JSON.parse('{ }');
   console.log("test - " + jsonpack.auto);

var jsonpack2 = JSON.stringify(jsonpack);
    console.log("test - " + jsonpack2.auto);


var jsonpack3 = JSON.stringify(jsonpack, null, ' ');
    console.log("test - " + jsonpack3);


var obj = JSON.parse(jsonpack2);
    console.log("test - " + obj);

 var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    console.log("test - " + keys[0]);
```

Comment: `momo goto 4 if false === true ? auto : false`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyym5bra/

Comment: @adeneo How parse - var strdate = "momo,{auto: true, lock: true}" ?

Comment: Why don't you switch to using ***valid*** JSON instead, and it will be easy

Comment: @adeneo I can not now to use JSON. I know what JSON good format. Very Thank  You!)